# Can't list columns or query in MS Access 2003 linked server in SQL Server 2008 R2 using Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access, linked-server

I can however list the tables...

If I run `Exec sp_tables_ex 'LSTest'` I get a result with a list of tables.

But if I run

```
Exec sp_columns_ex 'LSTest', '<one of those table names>'
```

I get an empty list, and if I try to query them I also get nothing.

If I go into the properties of the Linked Server I have the `Be made using this security context` and I use the `Remote login:` and `With password:` for the workgroup file that I would normally use in MS Access.

If I try to script a query by right clicking the table name in the linked server, instead of a select statement I get the following:

```
-- [LSTest]...[Tablename] contains no columns that can be selected or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Set your SystemDB File in the Registry

Note that you can only specify ONE of these damn things.

### On 32-bit Windows

If your Windows installation on which your SQL Server instance installed is 32-bit which is doubtful...use the following key to set the path to your MS-Access Workgroup file (`*.mdw`):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\SystemDB`

### On 64-bit Windows

On the other hand if your Windows installation on which your SQL Server Instance is installed, is 64-bit, (more likely) set the path to your MS-Access Workgroup file (`*.mdw`) here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Jet 4.0\Engines\SystemDB`

## 2. Create your linked server to MS Access

```
USE [master]
GO

-- Create a new linked table
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server='LinkedServerToMSAccessMDB',
@provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
@srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for Jet',
@datasrc = 'E:\DB_local\MyMDB.mdb'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@rmtsrvname='LinkedServerToMSAccessMDB',
@useself='FALSE',
@locallogin=NULL,
@rmtuser='someuser',
@rmtpassword='daspasswd'
GO
```

## 3. Make sure that your database credentials are passed to the Workgroup File `(.mdw)` when running a query from the `(.mdb)`

Now if you want to make sure that the password is being passed correctly after running this....in the `Object Explorer` panel, in `<server-name>\Server Objects\Linked Servers`, right click it and click `refresh`...your new `LinkedServerToMSAccessMDB` should now appear in the list, right click it and select `Properties`

In the window that appears next in the `Select a page` panel, click `Security` and then in the `For a login no defined in the list above, connections will:` radio button list, select the `Be made using this security context:` (if you don't want to be particular about what network users have access to it....otherwise use the mappings) and then in enter the username and password you would normally use to access MS Access using your `.mdw` file in the `Remote login:` and `With password:` text boxes.

## 4. Run a Query

After you click `OK` you should now be able to run a `select` on the `.mdb` file so that you can create a `VIEW` in a schema for some specified user.

```
SELECT [Field1]
  FROM [LinkedServerToMSAccessMDB]...[T_Table1]
GO
```

Comment: If you're wondering why you're SHOW PLAN doesn't work, it's a good bet this is the issue.